# SSL certificate in multi tier scenario

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate

Application A sends a request with certificate X, to B. Can service B send the same certificate X to another service C?

In .Net web api applicaiton (B), is there any configuration that handles this?

**Update**
I'm able to use `Request.GetClientCertificate` and add it in WebRequestHandler to HttpClient of Service C. However I'm still getting an error 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)'

Comment: I have to say it depends, and in many cases it won't work as B needs its own, but in others it simply works. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to use a common certificate that can be used to authenticate a service which acts as a client to another service.

Comment: It would be pretty strange to do so, but if the certificate was issued for both purposes, then you can use it of course. But there are various Windows level settings to change, and nothing is automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the reuse of certificate was not working - we were getting 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)' error. 
We had to pick the certificate from store and proceed with it.